# "binding" between factory and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to return a scope for binding from a factory to a controller. it would be ideal if i could pass the name so it could be dynamic. Here's what I have so far

```
.factory('urlWatch', function (urlFactory) {
    var _this = this;
    return {
        listenToUrl: function (scope, moduleName, stateName) {
          scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
            console.log(scope.bind);
            scope = urlFactory.parseState(moduleName, stateName);

          });
        }  
    };
    return _this;
});
```

and in the controller I have

```
$scope.mod1m3 = urlWatch.listenToUrl($scope, "module1", "mod1");
```

So this does not work but if I change the factory to look like this

```
 listenToUrl: function (scope, moduleName, stateName) {
          scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
            console.log(scope.bind);
            scope.mod1m3 = urlFactory.parseState(moduleName, stateName);

          });
        }
```

What i was trying to do is change it to

```
  listenToUrl: function (scope, moduleName, stateName, bind) {
          scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {

            scope.bind = urlFactory.parseState(moduleName, stateName);

          });
        }
```

and

```
  $scope.mod1m3 = urlWatch.listenToUrl($scope, "module1", "mod1", "mod1m3");
```

however it doesn't seem to want to connect the 2, I'm getting :

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '$on' of undefined
```

Unsure how i can get it to connect to get it to work as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Your factory `urlWatch` is weird. You return the object containing the `listenToUrl` method (so far so good), then you return `_this`. The last return is unreachable.

Comment: Yeah, haha sorry, i realized that and removed it, iw as playing around with something else and forgot to delete everything out. good catch. @MichaelP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the $scope attributre should be dynamic and saved in variable `bind` use:

```
listenToUrl: function (scope, moduleName, stateName, bind) {
  scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {

    // use scope like an associative array
    scope[bind] = urlFactory.parseState(moduleName, stateName);
  });
}
```

In the controller it is sufficient, if you use.

```
urlWatch.listenToUrl($scope, "module1", "mod1", "mod1m3");
```

$scope.mod1m3 will then be whatever parseState returns